# How to show the conditional entropy $H(Y|X)$ is equal to $H(X+Y|X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

I have a random variable $X$ that takes the values $x_1,x_2,...,x_4$ and $Y$ takes the values $y_1,y_2,...,y_s$.I define $Z=X+Y$ , and I'm trying to show that $H(Z|X)=H(Y|X).$

I know that $$P(Z=z)=\sum_{x\in{X}}{P(X=x)\cdot{P(Y=z-x)}}$$ but I'm not sure how to expand $$H(Y|X)=\sum_{x\in{X},y\in{Y}}p(x,y)log_2\frac{p(x)}{p(x,y)}$$ to $H(Z|X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your definitions:$$\begin{align}\mathsf H(Z\mid X)&=\sum_{x,z}p_{\small X,Z}(x,z)\log(p_{\small X}(x)/p_{\small X,Z}(x,z))\\[1ex]&=\sum_{x,y} p_{\small X,Z}(x,x+y)\log(p_{\small X}(x)/p_{\small X,Z}(x,x+y))\\[2ex]\mathsf H(Y\mid X)&=\sum_{x,y} p_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\log(p_{\small X}(x)/p_{\small X,Y}(x,y))\end{align}$$

Now consider that for discrete random variables, $X,Y$, and $Z=X+Y$ we have : $$p_{\small X,Z}(x,x+y)=p_{\small X,Y}(x,y)$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on why $p_{\small X,Z}(x,x+y)=p_{\small X,Y}(x,y)$ ? I don't understand it

Comment: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x,Z=x+y)&=\mathsf P(X=x,X+Y=x+y)\\&=\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)\end{align}$$ Because the event of $X=x$ and $X+Y=x+y$, is exactly the event of $X=x$ and $Y=y$. @user3133165

Comment: Yes thank you and just to understand more, is there an example where $H(Z)=H(X)+H(Y)$ is possible ?

Comment: Here is a simple example: Let $Z = (X, Y)$, so it's a vector whose indices are the random variables $X$ and $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $H(Z) = H(X) + H(Y)$. Plugging in $p_Z(x,y) = p_{X, Y}(x,y)$ in to the definition of entropy gives you the result.

Comment: Would you kindly give a simple example with numbers for $Z=X+Y$ and ill see if the calculations are correct, i have tried taking X and Y to be \begin{align}
X =Y= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
                0 & \hspace{5mm}, p=\frac{1}{2} \\
                1 & \hspace{5mm}, p=\frac{1}{2} \\
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm guessing the equality above means identically distributed and not that they always take the same value. Then, the joint probability distribution $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$, specifies the dependency between $X,Y$. You can already write $p_Z(z)$ in terms of $p_{X, Y}(x,y)$ for the three possible values $Z$ can take. Moreover, for these fixed $p_X(x), p_y(y)$, you already know $H(X), H(Y)$. Try and see if you can find a joint distribution on $(X,Y)$ that gives you what you want.

Comment: I have calculated and got that $H(Z)=1.5,H(X)=H(Y)=1$, am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Once again, $H(Z)$ is not fixed until you specify $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Defining the marginal distributions do not fully define the joint probabilities of the two random variables. What you're looking for is the values of $p_Z(i)$, such that $H(Z) = \sum_{i=0}^2 -p_Z(i)\log(p_Z(i)) = H(X) + H(Y) = 2$. By $Z = X + Y$ definition, $p_Z(0) = p_{X,Y}(0,0), p_Z(1) = p_{X,Y}(1,0) + p_{X,Y}(0,1)$ and $p_Z(2) = p_{X,Y}(1,1)$. If you find such four probability values that make up the joint distribution $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$, you have your answer.

Comment: If it's not clear to you why $Z$ is not fully characterized by only $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$, study the 4-page long Section 2.5 (page 76) of [this book](https://vfu.bg/en/e-Learning/Math--Bertsekas_Tsitsiklis_Introduction_to_probability.pdf) to get a better understanding of joint distributions.

Comment: @curlycharcoal just one last thing i took $p(X=0,Y=0)=0,p(X=0,Y=1)=\frac{1}{2},p(X=1,Y=0)=\frac{1}{4},p(X=1,Y=1)=\frac{1}{4}$ for the joint probability, but then i couldn't figure out the probabilities $p(X=0,1) ,p(Y=0,0)$.

Comment: $P(X=0) = P(X=0,Y=0) + P(X=0, Y=1)$ and so on.

Comment: Also, I think there is a typo in your previous answer. For the values you gave $p_Z(z) = [0, 3/4, 1/4]$. What you want is a vector of the form $[1/4, 1/2, 1/4]$ to get $H(Z) = 2$. I think you need to swap the values for $P(X=1, Y=0)$ and $P(X=0, Y=0)$

Comment: @curlycharcoal Yes thank you i figured out the table but now im confused of the values i should set for $p_X(x) = [?,?]$ and $p_Y(y) = [?,?]$ , to make sure that $H(Z)$ is indeed the sum $H(X)+H(Y)$. I need the values of the probabilities to calculate these two entropy

Comment: $p_X(x)  = \sum_{y=0}^1 p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and similarly $p_Y(y)  = \sum_{x=0}^1 p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. For example, $p_{X,Y}(0,0) = p_{X,Y}(1,1) = p_{X,Y}(1,0) = p_{X,Y}(0,1) = 1/4$ and hence $p_X(x) = p_Y(y) = [1/2, 1/2]$ works for you

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: you know the chain rule : $H(X,Z)=H(Z)+H(X \mid  Z) = H(X)+H(Z\mid X)$. The same equation is valid conditioned on a third variable $Y$

$$ H(Z\mid Y) +H(X\mid Z,Y) = H(X\mid Y)+H(Z\mid X,Y) $$

Now, let $Z=X+Y$

We have $H(Z\mid X,Y)=0$ , because $Z=g(X,Y)$

But we also have $H(X\mid Z,Y) =0$ for the same reason (given $Z,Y$ we know $X$).

Hence $$  H(X+Y\mid Y) = H(X\mid Y)$$

Actually this proves a more general result:

$$  H(g(X,Y) \mid Y) = H(X\mid Y)$$
for any function $g$  that is invertible wrt the first argument; i.e $g(x_1,y) = g(x_2,y) \implies x_1 = x_2$.